# How to validate input from a user in COBOL to accept only numbers > 1

Tags: cobol

I have a variable  `quantity` with `pic X (4)`.  How can I validate the input to DISPLAY `invalid quantity` if the quantity entered is not a number or no quantity is entered or `0` is entered.

I have tried `IF QUANTITY IS NUMERIC` but it didn't work. I calculate the total cost by using:

```
COMPUTE TOTAL = FUNCTION NUMVAL (QUANTITY)  * PRICE
```

Comment: Please check the updated answer and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers - please either comment about unclear parts or vote + accept.

Answer (score 2):

This highly depends on the compiler (and the version) you have - please add this missing information.

In general: *all user input should be validated* and in your case you want to use a numeric index, which should be `pic 9(04)`. Depending on the compiler (version) this already leads to "only numeric data in the field", if not you may could use `MOVE FUNCTION NUMVAL (input-field) TO quantity` leading to the same result.

Afterwards you just have to check if `quantity` is within the valid bounds of your `OCCURS`:

`quantity <= max-entries AND NOT = 0` for fixed-length occurs or

`quantity <= depending-field AND NOT = 0` for `OCCURS max-entries DEPENDING ON depending-field`

**Note**: Using `FUNCTION NUMVAL` on an invalid input like " z " will lead to `0` which is checked already, so you get the information "invalid" for both input of a zero number and a "string" entered (with a single check).

Comment: I don't know how to check my compiler version but i'm using Vista TN 3270 1.27. I realized that the compiler sees an input of  'a' as '1000', 'b' as '2000' and so on for PIC 9(4), while continuing to the ORDER SUMMARY of my program. Also an input of '1' is recognized as '1000'. I think i can fix the 'thousand' for the numeric input using MOVE TO and FUNCTION NUMVAL , but  I want it to reject non-numbers and just  display 'invalid quantity'.

Comment: Using the outlined technique will lead to non-numbers result in `0` which is an invalid number so you get the information you want (with a single check). Added this to the answer.
If you don't know the COBOL compiler version you likely at least now the COBOL compiler you use, don't you?